# include and using namespace in C++

Tags: c++, include, using, using-statement

for using `cout`, I need to specify both:

```
#include<iostream>
```

and

```
using namespace std;
```

**Where is `cout` defined? in `iostream`, correct? So, it is that `iostream` itself is there in namespace `std`?**

What is the meaning of both the statements with respect to using `cout`?

I am confused why we need to include them both.

Comment: @Neil Then what is the purpose of SO? To only ask questions that have no way of being answered by reading a book or searching the internet?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: okay! no more stupid questions after this one, without reading the concepts from a book.

Comment: @Kevin Anyone that thinks they can learn C++  by asking questions on SO is deluding themselves, and wasting our time.

Comment: I think the question is appropriate for SO.  SO wasn't meant to be reserved only for obscure/advanced questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`iostream` is the name of the file where cout is defined. On the other hand, `std` is a namespace, equivalent (in some sense) to Java's package.

cout is an instance defined in the `iostream` file, inside the std namespace.

There could exist another `cout` instance, in another namespace. So to indicate that you want to use the `cout` instance from the `std` namespace, you should write

`std::cout`, indicating the scope.

```
std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
```

To avoid the `std::` everywhere, you can use the `using` clause.

```
cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
```

They are two different things. One indicates scope, the other does the actual inclusion of `cout`.

## In response to your comment

Imagine that in iostream two instances named `cout` exist, in different namespaces:

```
namespace std{
   ostream cout;
}
namespace other{
   float cout;//instance of another type.
}
```

After including `<iostream>`, you'd still need to specify the namespace. The `#include` statement doesn't say "Hey, use the cout in std::". That's what `using` is for, to specify the scope.

Comment: @Tom: When I already included the file (`iostream`), I specified which definition of `cout` to use. Now the compiler knows what defination to use. So, what is the problem then. I am still confused as to why I need to say that it is in `std` namespace. That should have been necessary if there was some confusion. Here, there is no confusion as there is only one defination of `cout`.

Comment: @cambr:  No, you specified a definition of `cout` to use.  There's no reason you couldn't define `int cout;` afterwards, although it's not a good idea.  Arguably, the C++ standard could have required that namespaces be ignored if there's only one namespace with a given symbol, but it didn't, and I can't think of a language using namespaces where it does.

Answer (score 2):

If your C++ implementation uses C style header files (many do) then there is a file that contains something similar to:

```
#include ... // bunches of other things included

namespace std {

... // various things

extern istream cin;
extern ostream cout;
extern ostream cerr;

... // various other things

}
```

std is the namespace that the C++ standard says most of the standard things should reside in.  This is to keep from overpopulating the global namespace, which could cause you difficulty in coming up with names for your own classes, variables, and functions which aren't already used as names for standard things.

By saying

```
using namespace std;
```

you are telling the compiler that you want it to search in the namespace std in addition to the global namespace when looking up names.
If the compiler sees the source line:

```
return foo();
```

somewhere after the `using namespace std;` line it will look for `foo` in various different namespaces (similar to scopes) until it finds a foo that meets the requirements of that line.  It searches namespaces in a certain order.  First it looks in the local scope (which is really an unnamed namespace), then the next most local scope until over and over until outside of a function, then at the enclosing object's named things (methods, in this case), and then at global names (functions, in this case unless you've been silly and overloaded () which I'm ignoring), and then at the std namespace if you've used the `using namespace std;` line.  I may have the last two in the wrong order (std may be searched before global), but you should avoid writing code that depends on that.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` is logically defined within iostream.  By logically, I mean it may actually be in the file iostream or it may be in some file included from iostream.  Either way, including iostream is the correct way to get the definition of `cout`.

All symbols in iostream are in the namespace `std`.  To make use the the `cout` symbol, you must tell the compiler how to find it (i.e. what namespace).  You have a couple of choices:

```
// explicit
std::cout << std::endl;

// import one symbol into your namespace (other symbols must still be explicit)
using std::cout;
cout << std::endl;

// import the entire namespace
using namespace std;
cout << endl;

// shorten the namespace (not that interesting for standard, but can be useful
// for long namespace names)
namespace s = std;
s::cout << s::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#include <iostream>` references the header file that defines cout.  If you're going to use cout, then you will always need the include.

You do not need to `using namespace std;`.  That's simply allows you to use the shorthand `cout` and `endl` and the like, rather than `std::cout` and `std::endl` where the namespace is explicit.  Personally I prefer not to use `using namespace ...` since it requires me to be explicit in my meaning, though it is admittedly more verbose.

Comment: The compromise is `using std::cout; using std::endl;`, after which you can use `cout` and `endl` without qualification, without bringing the whole `std` namespace into the global namespace.